# mpdf - Text on first page extends on-to second page, overlapping the header

Tags: php, css, pdf-generation, mpdf

I am using the latest version of mPDF to render invoices. When I initiate a loop to display the products on the order, the text often extends past the boundaries of the page and to the next. Problem is, it overlaps the header on the next page.

I would like to either disable the header on all pages, except the first page. Or alternatively, force the overflow of text to obey the margin rules of the header.

For example, I may begin looping like so:

```
$html .= '<div style="clear:both; margin:auto;"><table>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $html .= '<tr><td>'.$term.'</td></tr>';
}   
$html .= '</table></div>';
```

If the HTML table has to continue to the next page, it just writes over the header. How can I tell mPDF to break the table up?

Comment: I have similar issue. Can someone help me with above question?

Comment: I ended up removing the <header> block and just writing my header into the body of my document.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with the following:

```
$param = '"en-GB-x","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3';
$mpdf = new mPDF($param);

$html_header='<div>This is my header content</div>';
$mpdf->setAutoTopMargin='stretch';
$mpdf->setHTMLHeader($html_header);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");
```

Calling the `setAutoTopMargin='strech'` before adding the header solved this problem for me.
The `$param` are just some default stolen from example, I haven't read what each value means.

Source: http://www.mpdfonline.com/repos/mpdfmanual.pdf (on page 107)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a such issue as well using mpdf, my savior was the use of this css property:

```
@media print {
#break-after {
    page-break-after: always;
     }
}
```

I put the break-after id at last div of the page, with this text on firt page will never go to next page.